# python xml.dom.minidom.Attr question

Tags: python, xml, minidom

Getting attributes using minidom in Python, one uses the "attributes" property. e.g. `node.attributes["id"].value`

So if I have `<a id="foo"></a>`, that should give me `"foo"`. `node.attributes["id"]` does not return the value of the named attribute, but an `xml.dom.minidom.Attr` instance. 
But looking at the help for `Attr`, by doing `help('xml.dom.minidom.Attr')`, nowhere is this magic `"value"` property mentioned. I like to learn APIs by looking at the type hierarchy, instance methods etc. Where did this `"value"` property come from?? Why is it not listed in the `Attr` class' page? The only data descriptors mentioned are `isId`, `localName` and `schemaType`. Its also not inherited from any superclasses. Since I'm new to Python, would some of the Python gurus enlighten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `minidom` is just an *implementation* of the `xml.dom` interfaces, so any docs specifically on minidom will only be about its peculiarities or limitations wrt `xml.dom` itself.

The `xml.dom` docs on [Attr](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html?highlight=xml.dom#dom-attr-objects) say, and I quote:

> Attr inherits from Node, so inherits
>   all its attributes.

The docs on [Node](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html?highlight=xml.dom#xml.dom.Node.nodeValue) actually name the attribute differently: `nodeValue`.  But, indeed...:

```
>>> import xml.dom.minidom as xdm
>>> dom = xdm.parseString('<foo bar="baz"/>')
>>> root = dom.documentElement
>>> atr = root.getAttributeNode('bar')
>>> atr.nodeValue
u'baz'
```

The fact that the documented `nodeValue` attribute has an _un_documented alias `value` may be considered unfortunate, but you can always stick with the documented, and therefore arguably *right*, attribute name, `nodeValue`.  Yes, it's verbose, but then so is all of `minidom`, as well as slower than the excellent [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree#xml.etree.ElementTree.Comment) (esp. in the latter's C implementation, `xml.etree.cElementTree`), so presumably if you choose to use `minidom` it must be because you *like* extensive verbosity...;-).

Comment: Thanks. ElementTree is too unlike the XML DOM processing I'm used to in other languages, hence went with minidom. The help(xml.dom.minidom.Attr) page did not list nodeValue in the "inherited from" Node or xml.dom.Node sections, even though it is clearly being inherited. Is there a way to inspect (as in reflection) Python classes and types, without relying on 'help' documentation pages that choose to selectively omit key (public!) properties or methods?

Comment: @rudy, `inspect.getmembers(atr)` will show you all the 65 attributes and methods (as pairs `(name, value)`) of object `atr`.  You can be more selective, too, of course.

Comment: Grrreat! Just what I needed. Thanks Alex!

Comment: The value property of attributes is documented in the W3C DOM spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-221662474

Answer (score 0):

Geez, never noticed that before.  You're not kidding, `node.value` isn't mentioned anywhere.  It is definitely being set in the code though under `def __setitem__` in xml.dom.minidom.

Not sure what to say other than, it looks like you'll have to use that.